# Using .toUpperCase() in conjunction with .includes()

Tags: javascript, case-sensitive

I'm trying to search through an array using the .includes() method. I don't want an element that is indeed in the array to go undetected using the .includes() method due to case sensitivity. Therefore, I am attempting to use .toUpperCase() in conjunction with .includes()

I don't understand why my code is not working.

```
var euroTour = ["France", "the Netherlands", "the UK", "Spain",
                "Portugal"];

var findCountry = euroTour.toUpperCase().includes('FRANCE');
```

I expect that using the code above, that true would be written to the document. However, nothing is written. When I remove the .toUpperCase() method altogether, as expected, false is written to the document since the subject of the search 'FRANCE' is not the same thing as 'France', an actual element of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toUpperCase()` can only be used on strings and not on whole array which you we were doing. Use map and `capitalise` the strings in array and then check with

```
.includes
```

```js
var euroTour = ["France", "the Netherlands", "the UK", "Spain",
                "Portugal"];

var findCountry = euroTour.map((e)=>e.toUpperCase()).includes('FRANCE');
console.log(findCountry)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var euroTour = ["France", "the Netherlands", "the UK", "Spain", "Portugal"];


var findCountry = euroTour
  .map(country => country.toUpperCase())
  .includes('FRANCE');
 
console.log(findCountry);
 
 // A More General Solution
 
 function includesStrCaseInsensitive(arr, str){
  return arr
    .map(i => i.toUpperCase())
    .includes(str.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(includesStrCaseInsensitive(euroTour, 'FRANCE'));

console.log(includesStrCaseInsensitive(euroTour, 'FrANCE'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`includes` does not provide a case insensitive option. You can use `some` in conjunction with a case-insensitive regex to accomplish what you want:

```js
var euroTour = ["France", "the Netherlands", "the UK", "Spain", "Portugal"]

console.log(euroTour.some(country => /^france$/i.test(country)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a super beginner at JS and hadn't understood regex's when you commented this response. I took the time to l learn and your code was useful to testing my understanding of such.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `toUpperCase()` on the array `euroTour`, which isn't valid - it's only possible with strings. First `map` the array to upper case:

```
euroTour = euroTour.map(e => e.toUpperCase());
```

Then you can use `.includes()` on that:

```
euroTour.includes("FRANCE");
```

Demonstration:

```js
var euroTour = ["France", "the Netherlands", "the UK", "Spain",
  "Portugal"
];

euroTour = euroTour.map(e => e.toUpperCase());

var findCountry = euroTour.includes("FRANCE");
```